# Is it able to align line chart at left margin in mixed chart?

Tags: chart.js

I'd like to align line chart at left margin in mixed chart as follow.

[image]

But when I added line chart in data, it's automatically aligned to centers according to existing bar chart as follow.

https://jsfiddle.net/daehyung/cvekgadf/4/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
            type: 'bar',
        label: 'A',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
            type: 'line',           
        label: 'B',
        data: [10, 8, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        borderWidth: 1,
        steppedLine: true
            }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

Comment: What are you wanting  to align exactly?

Comment: I'd like to make the data points of the line chart to be started at the left end. Re-uploaded the edited photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this purely by configuration in chart.js.  After browsing through the source, I see that line charts get set with a `offset = true` property internally when they appear on a combo bar chart.

Therefore, the only way to achieve this behavior is to extend the line chart and implement your own function to control the setting of this `offset` variable.  It turns out it's not that difficult to do.  Here is an example (note, the `offset` variable is only set in the line chart's `updateElement()` function).

```
var helpers = Chart.helpers;

Chart.controllers.LineNoOffset = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  updateElement: function(point, index, reset) {
    var me = this;
    var meta = me.getMeta();
    var custom = point.custom || {};
    var dataset = me.getDataset();
    var datasetIndex = me.index;
    var value = dataset.data[index];
    var yScale = me.getScaleForId(meta.yAxisID);
    var xScale = me.getScaleForId(meta.xAxisID);
    var pointOptions = me.chart.options.elements.point;
    var x, y;
    var labels = me.chart.data.labels || [];
    var includeOffset = false;

    // Compatibility: If the properties are defined with only the old name, use those values
    if ((dataset.radius !== undefined) && (dataset.pointRadius === undefined)) {
      dataset.pointRadius = dataset.radius;
    }
    if ((dataset.hitRadius !== undefined) && (dataset.pointHitRadius === undefined)) {
      dataset.pointHitRadius = dataset.hitRadius;
    }

    x = xScale.getPixelForValue(typeof value === 'object' ? value : NaN, index, datasetIndex, includeOffset);
    y = reset ? yScale.getBasePixel() : me.calculatePointY(value, index, datasetIndex);

    // Utility
    point._xScale = xScale;
    point._yScale = yScale;
    point._datasetIndex = datasetIndex;
    point._index = index;

    // Desired view properties
    point._model = {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      skip: custom.skip || isNaN(x) || isNaN(y),
      // Appearance
      radius: custom.radius || helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(dataset.pointRadius, index, pointOptions.radius),
      pointStyle: custom.pointStyle || helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(dataset.pointStyle, index, pointOptions.pointStyle),
      backgroundColor: me.getPointBackgroundColor(point, index),
      borderColor: me.getPointBorderColor(point, index),
      borderWidth: me.getPointBorderWidth(point, index),
      tension: meta.dataset._model ? meta.dataset._model.tension : 0,
      steppedLine: meta.dataset._model ? meta.dataset._model.steppedLine : false,
      // Tooltip
      hitRadius: custom.hitRadius || helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(dataset.pointHitRadius, index, pointOptions.hitRadius)
    };
  },
});
```

Once your new chart type is defined, then you have to change your configuration to use this new type.

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/KWyYWY) showing the final result (and demonstrating how to do this).

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer targets v2.5.0.

Comment: @jordanwillis I figured out how to improve your solution and posted it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by @jordanwillis I figured out a bit better method, that is compatible with chart.js `2.7.*` , and should be more safe to use with future versions, because it reuses more of existing code:

```
Chart.controllers.LineNoOffset = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    updateElement: function(point, index, reset) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateElement.call(this, point, index, reset);
        const meta = this.getMeta();
        const xScale = this.getScaleForId(meta.xAxisID);
        point._model.x = xScale.getPixelForValue(undefined, index-0.5);
    },
});
```