# In mixed chart containing bars and a line, how to extend the line outside of the chart in both directions?

Tags: chart.js2

I have this chart, which has line and bars:

[image: Chart]

Is it possible to somehow extend the line outside of the chart in both directions? This line serves an important role, it is sort of a "limit" for bars, I just don't want for it to start at the center of the first bar, and to end at the center of the final bar.

I can extend it to the right by simply extending the dataset of the line, but is it possible to extend it also to the left somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out answer based on answer from this question: [Is it able to align line chart at left margin in mixed chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858440/is-it-able-to-align-line-chart-at-left-margin-in-mixed-chart/47398412#47398412)

I'm extending line type like this:

```
Chart.controllers.LineNoOffset = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    updateElement: function(point, index, reset) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateElement.call(this, point, index, reset);
        const meta = this.getMeta();
        const xScale = this.getScaleForId(meta.xAxisID);
        point._model.x = xScale.getPixelForValue(undefined, index-0.5);
    },
});
```

Now the `LineNoOffset` type of the line will start from the left border of the chart, which fulfills my need.